# How can I get the real password via hook_user_update()?

Tags: 7, users

I want to change the current user password, and get the new password(the real password, not md5 encryption) when edit the account profile via user profile form(e.g.: example.com/user/1/edit) and save. would anyone can tell me how to do that? I tried using hook_user_update(), but it didn't succeed.

I mean I want to change the current user password, and I want to get the new password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) (or one of it relatives) such that it [array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) a new submission handler to the user update form. The submission handler should add the password to the `$form_state['values']` array. You also have to add the same key to `$form_state['user']`, because of the way [user_profile_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_profile_form_submit/7) calculates which keys from `$form_state['values']` to pass as `$edit` to your [hook_user_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) implementation.

If you did not insist on using [hook_user_update()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7), I'd suggest handling your custom additions to the password update directly in your submission handler.

By the way, Drupal 7 does not use a simple MD5 hash to store passwords.

Comment: I'm not going to add another answer, as the useful bit is already here - but there is no way to get a readable password out of Drupal.  To quote Kiamlaluno from [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18477/send-users-password-in-mail):  *Drupal doesn't encrypt the password and [save] it in the database, but it saves in database the hash of the password, which is the value returned from a one-way function;*

Comment: I try to add a drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['pass']) to the function user_profile_form_submit, and return the real password. but I dont want to hark code, so I want to get it on other customize module.

Comment: I just want to receive the new password via form widget (drupal 7 this widget's id is :edit-pass-pass1), and use this password to single sign on with other system. In order to make data synchronization,when password has changed, another system will changed at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

How about reading it directly from $_REQUEST array? I've added code like this:

```
function hook_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category){
 echo $_REQUEST['pass']['pass1'];
}
```

and it works.