# I want to get the real password(not md5 encryption) when edit the account profile via user profile form and save. how to do that?

Tags: 7, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the real password via hook_user_update()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44866/how-can-i-get-the-real-password-via-hook-user-update)

I want to change the current user password, and get the new password(the real password, not md5 encryption) when edit the account profile via user profile form(e.g.: example.com/user/1/edit) and save. would anyone can tell me how to do that? I tried using hook_user_update(), but it didn't succeed.

Comment: I mean I want to change the current user password, and I want to get the new password.

Comment: sorry, I dont know, how to delete this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot decrypt the password due to security reasons. Drupal 7 uses SHA512 by default with a salt. It will perform multiple hashes on the password. It's highly impossible to decrypt password.

See the better explanation provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315121/how-can-i-decrypt-passwords-hashed-using-the-md5-algorithm-from-a-drupal-databas).

**To reset the password see the solution provided** [here](http://drupal.org/node/1023428).

Comment: I just want to receive the new password via form widget (drupal 7 this widget's id is :edit-pass-pass1), and use this password to single sign on with other system.  In order to make data synchronization,when password has changed, another system will changed at the same time.

Comment: You can form alter the widget form and get the value using $form_state['values'], call the additional submit function to sync to another system . But, it's a not recommended to read user passwords, ideal way is to encrypt passwords and store them in another system too !

Comment: Do you mean to use hook_form_alter()?

Comment: Yes, Use hook_form_alter, but i strongly recommend encrypting passwords in another system too.. !

Comment: thanks Anil Sager, would you tell me how to use hook_form_alter? this page is call user_profile_form.

Comment: you need to write a custom module, and define the function MYMODULE_form_user_register_form_alter(), where MYMODULE is the name of your module.  It actually implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter, (the form_id for the form can be found in a hidden field, in this case it's user_register_form) as found here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.