# How to add auto generate password link for admin?

Tags: 7, users

I am using Drupal 7 for my website.
I have two roles **administrator** and **IT**.
I want to add auto generate password link at the time change the password by superadmin or IT role and also send the mail to respective user.

Please help how to add this functionality in my site.

Comment: Please any one suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this functionality using [Password Quick Set](https://www.drupal.org/project/passquickset) module and doing a little bit of custom code.

Answer (score 2):

You can used `hook_user_presave()` to [get](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/69155/45675) the changed password in your module:

```
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category){
 echo $_REQUEST['pass']['pass1'];
}
```

and use the functions `hook_mail()` & `drupal_mail()` to [send](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/6678/46233) the email in `hook_user_presave()` with the changed password in `$_REQUEST['pass']['pass1']`.

Comment: Hi, Brian i am new in drupal so please let me know full process

Comment: You need a custom module that uses `hook_user_presave()` (to intercept password), `hook_mail()` (to define custom email), & `drupal_mail()` (to send mail in `mymodule_user_presave`). You can Google "Drupal 7 tutorial custom module" & "Drupal 7 drupal_mail" on  how to do that. There are many.