# modify password_reset or request_new_password?

Tags: 7, services, users

When building a mobile app, and using [services3](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) and/or my custom module, I have a specific requirement:

I want anonymous users to be able to receive their password, in plaintext, in their email, if they give me their email address and if their account exists. If their account doesnt exist, I want to send a different email. I have trouble finding out where to start.

Services has `user/request_new_password`, and `user/password_reset`, but both seem to send out a one-time-link through email. Is there an easy way to modify those handlers ?

Otherwise, what would be a good appraoch in my own module ? Just create an `entity_metadata_wrapper` around the user, set the pass, call save and send the email ?

PS.
Please dont start a discussion about that workflow, there is a reason for it. If you have additional advice for security *without* changing the workflow as described, I'm all ears.

Comment: I hope you went through [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18477/send-users-password-in-mail)

Comment: Now I have, thanks. Its fine to generate a new password and mail that out once. It should ofcourse stay encrypted in the db.

Comment: great! :) you can answer your own question and mark it as answered.

Comment: Oh. Well I'd prefer the system would go through the hoops when changing the password, if it has any hoops. Caches to clean up, sessions to invalidate .. I'd rather hook into something existing, if I can.